# Audiokit, how to playback a modified buffer in a tap?

Tags: ios, objective-c, real-time, audiokit, avaudioengine

I use Audiokit (in Objective-C) for realtime audio processing. I feed a C++ algorithm through a tap or lazy tap where the buffer is being modified.
I thought that would be obvious but...how can I playback the modified buffer in the output? Are taps only for analysis?

```
[self->microphoneGain.avAudioNode installTapOnBus:0 bufferSize:1024 format:format block:^(AVAudioPCMBuffer * _Nonnull buffer, AVAudioTime * _Nonnull when) {  
    if (buffer.frameLength == 0) {  
        return;
    }
    // Process data -> return modified buffer
    processData(buffer.floatChannelData[0], buffer.floatChannelData[1], buffer.frameLength);
    // -> How to play back buffer?
}];
```

Furthermore, I can't get taps buffer size lower than 4800 samples. What would be my best option to get a better latency? I read about AUAudioUnit subclassing, render callback or realtime mode for AudioEngine, but I'm quite lost when trying to implement one of these with AudioKit. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I managed to set a render callback which has apparently solved both of my problems.

```
AURenderCallbackStruct processingCallback;
processingCallback.inputProc = processingCalbackProc;
processingCallback.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void *)(self);
OSStatus status = AudioUnitSetProperty(AudioKit.engine.outputNode.audioUnit,
    kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
    kAudioUnitScope_Input,
    0,
    &processingCallback,
    sizeof(processingCallback));
if(status != noErr) {
    return false;
}

OSStatus processingCalbackProc (void *inRefCon,
                           AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                           const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                           UInt32 inBusNumber,
                           UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                           AudioBufferList *ioData)
{
    __unsafe_unretained MyClass *self = (__bridge MyClass *)inRefCon;
    printf("%u, ", (unsigned int)inNumberFrames); // -> low latency!

    if (!ioData) ioData = self->audioBufferList;
    OSStatus status = AudioUnitRender(AudioKit.engine.outputNode.audioUnit,
                                      ioActionFlags,
                                      inTimeStamp,
                                      1,
                                      inNumberFrames,
                                      ioData);
    if(status != noErr) { return status; }

    // Get buffers
    unsigned int inputChannels = 2;
    float *buffer[inputChannels];
    for (int i = 0; i < inputChannels; i++) {
        buffer[i] = (float *)ioData->mBuffers[i].mData;
    }

    // Process data
    processData(buffer[0], buffer[1], inNumberFrames);

    return noErr;
}
```

Now I can easily get buffers as low as 256samples (probably even less but not needed in my case) and when `buffer[n]`are modified, it outputs the modified buffers.
Everything seems to be fine, I just hope this is the right approach.

Comment: Taps are relatively slow and unpredictable, I wouldn't use them for any audio.  In AudioKit we use them to show data on plots.

Comment: Thanks @AureliusProchazka, I guess I found a solution, I edited my post.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Any chance you'd post a gist of your class @jcr?

Comment: @user1218464 I didn't do much than the code above honestly. It was just a test. AudioKit looks great, but I switched to a more low level audio programming.